# Step by step execution of javascript or Jquery in specific condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

We have a task to  append the given svg in a `DIV` and convert into inline `svg`  when a button click `(.button-new)`.

So we have a div`(#main-div)` with specific width and height , for example width and height  is **200 px.**

And we have an svg with  width and height is **50 px** . So there are `total_no_blocks =4` elements which fir into the container.

and we write the following code append the `div` with svg images.

```
for(var i =0;i<total_no_blocks;i++){
   $("#main-div").append("<img id=\"facebook-logo\" class=\"svg\"  src=\""+img_src+"\" width=\"100\" />");
}
```

and convert  to inline svg we are using the following code

https://gist.github.com/Bloggerschmidt/61beeca2cce94a70c9df

```
jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
    var $img = jQuery(this);
    var imgID = $img.attr('id');
    var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
    var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

    jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
        // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
        var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

        // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
        if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
        }
        // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
        if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
        }

        // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
        $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

        // Replace image with new SVG
        $img.replaceWith($svg);

    }, 'xml');

});
```

**The problem is javascript not working step by step .**

As per our code first 4 image need to  append in div , second it  converted to inline svg .

But what happens is that some time before load and show 4 image to main-div,  it starts converting to inline svg . As the result in first  time only 2 image loaded same time 3 image loaded or some time it is correct.

So the total code is like this [This is not complete code ]

```
$(".button-new").on("click",function(){
    $("#main-div").children().remove();

    for(var i =0;i<total_no_blocks;i++){

        $("#main-div").append("<img id=\"facebook-logo\" class=\"svg\"  src=\""+img_src+"\" width=\"100\" />");

    }



    jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
        var $img = jQuery(this);
        var imgID = $img.attr('id');
        var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
        var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

        jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
            // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
            var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

            // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
            }
            // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
            }

            // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
            $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

            // Replace image with new SVG
            $img.replaceWith($svg);

        }, 'xml');

    });


     function 3() etc.......

});
```

> I know javascript is synchronus but some cases like  ajax  it will
>   work step by step , because it is waiting for the return message

.

How  we  can control  the execution of script in current situation ?

What steps need to ensure that , all are executing step by step & all execution is properly finished  ?

Comment: AJAX stands for Asynchronous Javascript And XML, which is asynchronous...

Answer (score 2):

Let's sum up the scenario:

- User clicks on `.button-new` button
- element `#main-div` will be appended with `total_no_blocks` number of facebook logos, being `img.svg`
- The `img.svg` items are iterated
- An AJAX request is sent to the server to get the picture (in each iteration)
- The response is interpreted as an SVG and written instead of the tag having an `id`

The main problem is that your code assumes that the facebook logos are being waited for. This is not how it works. In fact, the tags are created instantly and the iteration which follows occurs after the creation of the tags, BUT these are images which are loaded from somewhere (unless cached) and that's asynchronous. You need to implement a `$("#main-div > img").load()` handler and put your logic which replaces the image there. This will wait for the specific tag to be loaded and do what needs to be done. However, you have other problems as well. Your `id` is `facebook-logo` in each case, which defeats the purpose of `id`s, which is, to identify the tag. So you need this change as well into your cycle:

```
$("#main-div").append("<img id=\"facebook-logo" + i + "\" class=\"svg\"  src=\""+img_src+"\" width=\"100\" />");
```

which will make the items unique. Lastly, I do not understand why do you generate images which will have no purpose whatsoever and will consequently be overriden by svg images. If this has educational or illustrative purpose, then you might want to consider wrapping your `$("#main-div > img").load()` handler into a `setTimeout`, waiting for a second, for example to allow the human eyes to see what was the initial image. If not, then you could simply use svg from the start to avoid all the hassle.

Comment: @abilasher you are welcome, I wish you all the best in your projects.

Comment: can you please summarize how will be the entire code ? Also here i am not using Ajax .But why you are saying An AJAX request is sent to the server to get the picture ?

Comment: @abilasher the answer for the first question is yes, but I will need a Fiddle from you to test the code to make sure everything is all right, there are no typos and so on. The answer to the second question is that there is an asynchronous request to the server to get the file(s) and this request is not being waited for to be finished. Therefore this is asynchronous. I do not factually know whether Javascript and XML is involved in the inner logic of the browser, it might be true in some browsers, but the way it works it is very similar to AJAX.

Comment: @abilasher so, maybe I was exaggerating a bit. What I really meant is that it is an asynchronous request and you can attach an event handler for the event when the file was successfully extracted. This handler would be very similar to the callback of an AJAX request.

Comment: @abilasher I do not have much experience with screen capturing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example where you can see what happens. Put a simple callback as parameter to your function.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SVG 001</title>
    <style>
      body{font-family:"Calibri", sans-serif;}
      svg{border:1px solid #eee;float:left;}
    </style>
  </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Offset Dasharray</h1>
      <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
        <path id="myPath" d="M 50 50 q 200 800 400 0" stroke="none"stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
      </svg> 
      <p id="astart"><p>
      <p id="aend"><p>
      <p id="acallback"><p>
      
      <script>
        var paintPathAni=function(path, duration, color, callback){
          easeInOutQuad= function (t) { return t<.5 ? 2*t*t : -1+(4-2*t)*t }
          var len=path.getTotalLength();  
          var aktLen;
          var sumSteps = duration / (1000/60) // 60 pics per second
          var step=1;
          var pathAnim;
          var anim=function(){
            aktLen = easeInOutQuad(step/sumSteps)*len; 
            path.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', aktLen + ' ' + (len - aktLen));
            path.setAttribute('stroke',color);
            if (step < sumSteps){
              step++;
              pathAnim = setTimeout(anim, 1000/60) //1000/60 pics/second
              } else {
                clearTimeout(pathAnim);
                path.setAttribute('stroke',"red");
                path.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray','none');
                if (callback) return callback();
              }
          }
          anim();   
      }
      astart.innerHTML="before function call";
      paintPathAni(myPath, 5000,'red',function(){acallback.innerHTML="callback call";});
      aend.innerHTML="after function call";
    </script>
  </body>  
  </html>
```